# If statement with multiple conditions where 1 statement is true does not work

Tags: php

I have the following statement

```
if ( !(strstr($Description1,'word1') OR strstr($Description1,'word2') OR
       strstr($Description2,'word1') OR strstr($Description2,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description3,'word1') OR strstr($Description3,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description4,'word2') OR strstr($Description4,'word2') OR 
       ($_POST['fine'] == x) OR ($_POST['fine'] == y) OR ($_POST['fine'] == z))) { 

    Action1
} else { 
    Action2
}
```

What it does if any of the statements is true it goes to `Action2`. What I want it to do is that if any the statements is  true go to `Action1`

Comment: take off the not **!**

Answer (score 0):

Keep the "or" bits within one set of brackets.
    if ($a == "a" || $b == "b"){ 
    Action1}
    else { Action2}

Answer (score 0):

why not just remove the `!` at the beginning or just switch `action1` and `action2`??

```
if ((strstr($Description1,'word1') OR strstr($Description1,'word2') OR
       strstr($Description2,'word1') OR strstr($Description2,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description3,'word1') OR strstr($Description3,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description4,'word2') OR strstr($Description4,'word2') OR 
       ($_POST['fine'] == x) OR ($_POST['fine'] == y) OR ($_POST['fine'] == z))) { 

    Action1
} else { 
    Action2
}
```

or

```
if ( !(strstr($Description1,'word1') OR strstr($Description1,'word2') OR
       strstr($Description2,'word1') OR strstr($Description2,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description3,'word1') OR strstr($Description3,'word2') OR 
       strstr($Description4,'word2') OR strstr($Description4,'word2') OR 
       ($_POST['fine'] == x) OR ($_POST['fine'] == y) OR ($_POST['fine'] == z))) { 

    Action2
} else { 
    Action1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I tried both and it is still not working if any statement is true it goes to action 2.